# Tensorflow no module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal' (DLL's appear to be fine)

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-import, importerror

I had to reinstall python (it was a whole mess but to my knowledge, it does appear to have fully reinstalled without remnants) and, while I never ran it beforehand, I recently have wanted to start running TensorFlow, unfortunately, whenever I try to import the module it raises an error. I have spent the last days adding every possible Cuda and Cudnn dll to my paths and every other solution I have found suggested but none of them have had any effect. (random information I don't think will be relevant but am putting here just in case: Pip stopped finding TensorFlow so I used the google link when installing via pip, while I do have the most up to date python 3 I also have python 2.7, if I run a script that imports it with python3 the script just ends then and there with no error but if I run it with the traditional "python" command (from cmd) it raises the error below)
os: Windows 10

```
Python 3.8.1 (tags/v3.8.1:1b293b6, Dec 18 2019, 23:11:46) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Paul Duke\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', [dirname(__file__)])
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\imp.py", line 296, in find_module
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Paul Duke\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Paul Duke\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Paul Duke\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow_internal
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Paul Duke\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\Paul Duke\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Paul Duke\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Paul Duke\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', [dirname(__file__)])
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\imp.py", line 296, in find_module
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Paul Duke\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Paul Duke\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Paul Duke\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow_internal
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using Python 3.8.

from the file list of
[pypi for tensorflow](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/#files)
and [pypi for tensorflow](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-gpu/#files),

here is the [tracking issue on github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33374)

So just use an old version of python will solve you problem. I'd suggest you using [anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/) or miniconda to manage you deeping learning dev environment.